# How to remove a blank horizontal line from CV template?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am writing my academic CV in a `Latex` template I found online. It has a contact information section on the top which after compilation looks like this:
[image]

I tried my best to figure out why there is a blank horizontal line against the word CONTACT but it was in vain. It seems the address is beginning against the word INFORMATION. Will appreciate any help. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
        marginparwidth=30.5mm,    
        marginparsep=1.5mm,       
        margin=1.9cm,             
        includemp]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage{color,hyperref}

\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
    {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
         {\large #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
             \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
     \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
\noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\hyphenpenalty=10000\raggedright #1}}}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}


\begin{document}
\makeheading{\Huge{\textsc{John Doe}}}

\section{Contact Information}
%
\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{1.85in}%
\newlength{\spacewidth}\setlength{\spacewidth}{20pt}
%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}}%

% Address box
\parbox{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}{%
Center for Big Shot Studies\\
The Haughty University\\
Viale Brillianca, 23, 00197 Rome RM, Italy}

&
\parbox[m][5\baselineskip]{\spacewidth}{} &
\parbox{\rcollength}{%
\textit{Mobile:} +39-00000-11111 \\
\textit{E-mail:} \href{djogn@haughty.it}{djogn@haughty.it}\\
\textit{WWW:} \href{https://haughty.com/}{haughty.com/}}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but the `times` package is deprecated. Better to load `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` (if you need math).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `tabular` without the parboxes should work perfectly fine. Instead of calculated column widthy, you could aslo just use a simple `tabular*` in combination with `\extracolsep{\fill}}` in order to make sure, the table uses the available text width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
        marginparwidth=30.5mm,    
        marginparsep=1.5mm,       
        margin=1.9cm,             
        includemp]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage{color,hyperref}

\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
    {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
         {\large #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
             \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
     \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
\noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\hyphenpenalty=10000\raggedright #1}}}%
\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}


\begin{document}
\makeheading{\Huge{\textsc{John Doe}}}

\section{Contact Information}
%
\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{1.85in}%
\newlength{\spacewidth}\setlength{\spacewidth}{20pt}
%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}@{}}%
Center for Big Shot Studies && \textit{Mobile:} +39-00000-11111\\
The Haughty University      && \textit{E-mail:} \href{djogn@haughty.it}{djogn@haughty.it}\\
Viale Brillianca, 23, 00197 Rome RM, Italy && \textit{WWW:} \href{https://haughty.com/}{haughty.com/}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}l@{}}%
Center for Big Shot Studies & \textit{Mobile:} +39-00000-11111\\
The Haughty University      & \textit{E-mail:} \href{djogn@haughty.it}{djogn@haughty.it}\\
Viale Brillianca, 23, 00197 Rome RM, Italy & \textit{WWW:} \href{https://haughty.com/}{haughty.com/}
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate it but what it is in this template which is causing this issue? Just want to understand it.

Comment: The missing optional argument `t` to top align the parboxes was causing the issue in the original example code. However, the parboxes are not needed here, so I included two simplified examples in my answer to show how you could achieve the same (or at lease a very similar) output with less and cleaner code.

Comment: many thanks for not only helping me understand the problem but also for pointing me towards use of `tabular*` and `\extracolsep{\fill}}`. Your code is cleaner too.